# Unable to get a transaction out there!

Tags: transaction

I installed a node following various instructions and have it accessible here:

```
curl http://myiotanode.hopto.org:14265   -X POST   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'X-IOTA-API-Version: 1.2'   -d '{"command": "getNodeInfo"}'
{"appName":"IRI","appVersion":"1.4.1.4","jreAvailableProcessors":2,"jreFreeMemory":66118256,"jreVersion":"1.8.0_151","jreMaxMemory":464519168,"jreTotalMemory":206569472,"latestMilestone":"ZDCYRDBFQZIQAJEPWZBFFTZECVCXSPEP9EEOHMRAXSHWQHKMFDNQJNEMJQIYW9OHGPNMBICVBTGQ99999","latestMilestoneIndex":315935,"latestSolidSubtangleMilestone":"TKZXZXNWFBLK9OXZGQ9UYEST9QQCJLWJJSHWNBUMNVWYQLTPWYNLSIMGCMAZHGTMOTN9EXFPURLG99999","latestSolidSubtangleMilestoneIndex":243208,"neighbors":8,"packetsQueueSize":0,"time":1514906399621,"tips":614,"transactionsToRequest":3863,"duration":0}
```

I then tried to create a transaction and broadcast it. I think I did everything correctly, as my node spent a while doing proof of work etc, and eventually I was able to read the content of the tx, which was:

```
{ hash: 'WWLJZLHSKMQYBLOHNNTF9VELPEFKZLEWNJZVHDZFSVPQHUAXKVMUPGVWBYEHPDNZYZXQ9LEYA9Y999999',
  signatureMessageFragment: 'WCTC9D9DCDEAHDPCBDVC9DTC999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999',
  address: 'WHR9DHKTWYABMMGLQKOUJMQMKQQBZXTQHKVJIJCHWBOPYK9WDCLW9H9UZKRXOSNDHNISNNAGXRL9IZZWC',
  value: 0,
  obsoleteTag: 'DHPCVC999999999999999999999',
  timestamp: 1514718682,
  currentIndex: 0,
  lastIndex: 0,
  bundle: 'BLGMCG9ULLLGSH9HN99VYJCJQXLLMRONNKWBETZUKUEJGFIXIZSLLLPKBITTUVFDJGULWGHAOCNS9WTQX',
  trunkTransaction: 'FOVICVEADXPXWFGWMXYHKOYOZSRIJRLNGVXWSVKXDMU9HSRXR99BM9HYUCUAAROBMIHLWHXLXRHIA9999',
  branchTransaction: 'UWTPNOMQ9LGIBEMQ99IEVOZPCAZKERLVRNJQGOHRREHAVVM9QGQXAZRGUNC9KIMYDKFYETL9A9RLZ9999',
  tag: 'HDPCVC999999999999999999999',
  attachmentTimestamp: 1514718692316,
  attachmentTimestampLowerBound: 0,
  attachmentTimestampUpperBound: 12,
  nonce: 'ODGDJXQJEKKHXOJMZNPLBPCKGHS' }
```

But when I try to look for the tx or address at https://thetangle.org/search I can find nothing.

So I am at a loss. What am I doing wrong? Any help or pointers elsewhere would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If you search in tangle explorer for the [branch](https://iotasear.ch/hash/UWTPNOMQ9LGIBEMQ99IEVOZPCAZKERLVRNJQGOHRREHAVVM9QGQXAZRGUNC9KIMYDKFYETL9A9RLZ9999) and [trunk](https://iotasear.ch/hash/FOVICVEADXPXWFGWMXYHKOYOZSRIJRLNGVXWSVKXDMU9HSRXR99BM9HYUCUAAROBMIHLWHXLXRHIA9999) transaction you will see that they are both very old : 2 months and 2 weeks respectively.

Your node is indeed not sync and so is unable to give you recent tips.

Answer (score 2):

it seems your node is way out of sync. i think that explains it. latestMilestoneIndex should equal latestSolidSubtangleMilestoneIndex before trying to send a transaction.

{"latestMilestoneIndex":315935,"latestSolidSubtangleMilestoneIndex":243208}

Comment: Thanks! But I see that those numbers are not moving. So is there something I need to do to get my node syncing? I thought that just by running it and finding nieghbors it would do the syncing. What else do I need to do?

Comment: are you very sure you setup the node correctly???? http://iota.partners is a good resource. also hardware-specs could be a factor. the above resource states: "For a simple node that should not spam, a VPS (Virtual Private Server) with 2 cores and 4GB RAM (8GB / 4 cores are of course better) is currently sufficient. An SSD hard disk is highly recommended but not mandatory. The disk space does not have to be larger than 30GB and the data transfer traffic of almost all providers is so high that we can ignore it."